# jQuery Chosen dropdown inside of jqWidgets tab is not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen, jqxwidgets

I am using jqWidgets tabs with jQuery Chosen dropdowns inside the contents of tabs

The problem I am having is when I click to open the dropdown the div gets clipped off at the bottom of the tab - I expect the popup for the dropdown to overlay everything and display completely

See the following basic example to reproduce the behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/mPwWW/

How can I remedy this with minimal hacking of either of their style sheets?

```
<html>
<div style="width : 500px; height : 180px;">
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <label>Test:</label>
        <select id="target" style="width : 80px"></select>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
</html>

<script>
$("#tabs").jqxTabs({
        position : 'top',
        animationType : 'fade',
        selectionTracker: true,
        height : '180px'
    });

// the following lines are just for filling the sample dropdown with some values
var html = '';
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    html += '<option value="'+x+'">'+x+'</option>';
}
$("#target").html(html);
// apply the chosen library to this dropdown
$("#target").chosen();
</script>
```

Please see the fiddle code I did not replicate the document.ready call in my snippet above

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the div container that Chosen dropdown is in has a set height. So if Chosen extends further than the height of the container div, then it'll be cut off. What you can try is to add to Chosen dropdown:

```
position: absolute
```

That way it'll be brought out of the normal flow of the page, in other words, not restricted to the height of it's parent container.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at the chosen css and it looks like they already do apply position : absolute to the class "chzn-drop"